# Why is my table not showing?

Tags: php, html, csv, html-table, fgetcsv

I'm having some trouble with my website. It uses HTML with embedded PHP. I have a schedule page that pulls information from a CSV file and displays it as a table on the site, to make it easier to update schedules, but it's not working for some reason. Here's the code (I cut out the unimportant stuff).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
     $f = fopen("schedule.csv", "r");
     while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
     {
          $row = $line[0]; // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)
          $cells = explode(";",$row);
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach ($cells as $cell)
          {
               echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>\n";
     }
     fclose($f);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try opening the webpage, all I get is:

```
foreach ($cells as $cell) { echo ""; } echo "\n"; } fclose($f); ?>

" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "
```

I can't tell if I'm missing a punctuation or what. I basically copied it from another site that another programmer recommended to someone else, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you save your page as .php file?

Comment: Have you made sure your hosting supports `php`? Does your file end in .php?

Comment: No, it's an HTML with embedded PHP in it, which after doing research online is something I can do.  Or is that the problem?

Comment: It seems like your `php` file is not being parsed. Please check your server settings to see if php is installed. On unix servers this can be done using `$ php -v`

Comment: @DaCodeMonkey01 have you seen if it works now with the correction in my answer?

Comment: Sadly, no.  Still says the same thing.

Comment: @Peter  How do I check to see if PHP is installed on Firefox?

Comment: @DaCodeMonkey01 I just reupdated my code. Let me know if it works

Comment: Okay, update.  It seems that firefox doesn't run php.  I tried running that code as a PHP page with embedded html, and it didn't work.  It asked me if I wanted to open or save the PHP.  I think that might be why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
 $f = fopen("schedule.csv", "r");
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
 {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($line as $cell)
      {
           echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
 }
 fclose($f);
```

Comment: Now there's 3 opening parenthesis but 2 closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
     $f = fopen('schedule.csv', 'r');
     while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
     {
          $row = $line[0]; // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)
          $cells = explode(';',$row);
          echo '<tr>';
          foreach ($cells as $cell)
          {
               echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($cell) . '</td>';
          }
          echo '</tr><br/>';
     }
     fclose($f);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```